# Stop collection runner in pre-request script?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a collection with a single request in it. I’m using a .csv with collection runner to execute the request once per line in the .csv. The first column in the .csv is `Document ID`, and that’s the only variable I’m using from the .csv.

However, at the bottom of the .csv is a blank line followed by a few lines that aren’t pertinent to the running of the collection.

I’d like the collection to see the blank line (maybe via `pm.collectionVariables.get(‘Document ID’) == ''`) and stop executing.

Any suggestions on the best way to do that?

**UPDATE:**
Christian Baumann's answer below helped clarify the situation. I'm not only wanting to stop the collection, I'm wanting to stop the ***iterations of the collection***. There may not be a way to stop the iterations. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `If (....) { postman.setnextrequest(null) } `?

Comment: postman.setNextRequest() works on the next request. I'd like to stop the current request.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet in the pre-request script will do it, you might need to adapt the condition to make it work:

```js
var iterationData = pm.iterationData.toObject();
if (iterationData[‘Document ID’] == '') {
     throw new Error('End of CSV file reached!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! Because this is in Collection Runner, and because the value for Document ID is coming from the csv, the value for Document ID in the current iteration is not loaded by the time the pre-request script is run. However, I was able to get around this by this: var iterationData = pm.iterationData.toObject(); var docid = iterationData['Document ID']; if (docid == '')...

Comment: (continuing) However, throwing the Error only stops the request in the current iteration. The remaining iterations (which also have blank Document IDs) are continuing. So I get a string of Errors as the end of the csv file is reached. I wouldn't mind one error, but I don't want a string of errors. It would be nice to find a way to stop the iterations once an error has occurred.

Comment: (continuing) It may not be possible.

Comment: I didn't find anything to stop a collection run, so I guess it might not be possible at all. ‍♂️